# vsync on iOS: How does it work

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es

I'm trying to figure out how vsync works on iOS, in conjunction with `CADisplayLink`. The question I am trying to answer here is:

- What happens on iOS if I miss a frame on the CPU side?

I setup a few tests:

- Use a `CADisplayLink` timer with interval of 1 =~ 60Hz on iPhone
- Analyze time between timer invocations using both`[CADisplayLink timestamp]` and `mach_absolute_time()`

**Test 1: Base test:** Here, I just tracked 10000 samples:

```
timestamp-----
max: 16.762583
min: 16.627625
mean: 16.675080
variance: 0.000333

mach----------
max: 22.606042
min: 10.815958
mean: 16.675694
variance: 0.602793

diff----------
max: 5.941417
min: 0.000750
mean: -0.000615
variance: 0.607476
```

**Test 2: Frame miss due to short CPU wait:** Here, on frame X, I just sat in a spinlock for Y iterations. Logged frame times relative to frame X:

```
Y = 200000
-1: 16.72   17.85   (-1.13)
0:  16.66   15.37   (1.29)
1:  33.32   43.74   (-10.42) (*)
2:  16.74   4.34    (12.40) (*)
3:  16.61   16.70   (-0.10)
4:  16.71   16.65   (0.06)  

Y = 100000
-1: 16.66   16.50   (0.16)
0:  16.69   16.67   (0.02)
1:  16.63   22.21   (-5.58) (*)
2:  16.68   9.91    (6.77) (*)
3:  16.70   16.04   (0.67)
4:  16.69   16.70   (-0.01)
```

**Test 3: Same as Test 2, but using OS call to sleep for t seconds**

```
t = 0.03
-1: 16.67   16.54   (0.14)
0:  16.68   16.91   (-0.23)
1:  33.35   34.78   (-1.43) (*)
2:  16.68   14.93   (1.74) (*)
3:  16.68   16.87   (-0.20)
4:  16.67   16.48   (0.19)

t = 0.02
-1: 16.64   16.54   (0.09)
0:  16.72   16.91   (-0.19)
1:  16.66   20.79   (-4.13) (*)
2:  16.69   12.60   (4.08) (*)
3:  16.67   18.24   (-1.57)
4:  16.68   15.09   (1.59)

t = 3.0
-1: 16.68   16.74   (-0.07)
0:  16.63   16.58   (0.05)
1:  266.84  3004.04 (-2737.20) (*)
2:  2751.35 14.82   (2736.54) (*)
3:  16.66   16.80   (-0.14)
4:  16.68   15.86   (0.81)
```

**Observations:**

- Unlike Apple documentation, `CADisplayLink` does **NOT** wait for vsync in the event of a CPU frame miss.
- However, for small misses, it looks that's what Apple **wants** us to believe, via `[CADisplayLink timestamp]`
- My best explaination is something like:

---

1. `CADisplayLink` invocations only happen when either the graphics driver's command buffer is empty, or the GPU's command buffer is empty (and thus requests more commands from, or unblocks, the graphics driver).
2. The GPUs on the iPhone have vsync enabled - it **will** stall, and wait for the physical screen refresh before processing more GPU commands.
3. If our GPU and CPU frames are constantly under 16.6ms, we will be produce more GPU commands then the GPU can consume
4. As such, when the GPU stalls, it stops pulling commands from the driver, and once we fill the driver command buffer, our `CADisplayLink` stops being called.
5. After the vsync, the GPU is able to process more GPU commands, and thus is also able to pull commands from the driver. When there is enough room in the driver command queue, the driver notifies iOS that it needs more commands, and we get a `CADisplayLink` invocation.
6. (I can't tell if this drives the whole event loop on iOS, or whether the event loop is always running, and just polls the driver ever iteration to see if it can invoke `CADisplayLink`
7. Thus, we get our `CADisplayLink` being called roughly once every 16.6ms - a downstream result of a pipeline that **does** wait on vsync on the far end.
8. However, if we miss a frame on the CPU side, i.e. take slightly longer than 16.6ms to produce commands after the driver requests, its OK. There is still a frame or two (need to measure) worth of commands still in the pipeline. As long as we don't let the pipeline drain, we are fine: we can still have the GPU render 1 new frame, every 16.6ms, right on time with vsync
9. This is why `[CADisplayLink timestamp]` differs from the "actual" time, `mach_absolute_time()`.

For example, **Test2: i=100000**:

1. We ran a bunch of frames, easily under 16.6ms to pack the pipeline
2. We took a long time on a frame X (22.21ms)
3. However, the GPU as 1 frame behind: frame X-2 was on the screen, and when vsync happened, it didn't need frame X's commands, frame X-1's were there still there in the pipeline
4. By the time the next vsync happened, and the GPU **did** need frame X's commands, they were there.
5. After taking awhile on frame X, we were able to stuff the pipeline full after firing off frame X+1 quickly

Thus, to the user, no frame was ever dropped.

How far am I off the mark here? I wish I was a computer engineer.

Comment: Wasn't planning on such a long question - but writing it out helped clarify some stuff (hopefully, unless someone says I'm wayy off)